# My react app is not rendering after adding <Auth0Provider>

Tags: reactjs, auth0

I'm trying to add Auth0 to my react App, but when I wrap my  with  it stop rendering ONLY in phones while in development. In my computer everything works fine. I have no error in my console. Do you guys know why?

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client'
import './sass/index.scss'
import App from './App'
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
import { Auth0Provider } from '@auth0/auth0-react'

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement)

root.render(
    <React.StrictMode>
        <BrowserRouter basename='/tombola'>
            <Auth0Provider
                domain='******************'
                clientId='******************'
                authorizationParams={{
                    redirect_uri: `${window.location.origin}/tombola/callback`
                }}>
                <App />
            </Auth0Provider>
        </BrowserRouter>
    </React.StrictMode>
)
```

Comment: Have you checked your auth0 logs yet:  auth0 dashboard > monitoring > logs ?

Comment: Yes, there is nothing wrong

Comment: Have you tried different phones / browsers / internetconnections? The fact that it works on other devices (except your phone) and that no errors are given might suggest that it's a problem with your device instead of Auth0

Comment: Yes, same problem in every device and different browsers

Comment: You said 'ONLY phone' before, is it only phone or every device? and have you checked the browser console?

Comment: Sorry, I mean the problem is present only in phones. I've tried my PC and other PCs and it works fine. But in my phone and other phones I get this problem, and I've tried these phones with different browsers.